# Multiple sorting by alphabet and hexadecimal in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I want to sort an array by hex number and alphabet, but I have no idea how. My array looks something like this:

```
my @array = ( 
    "{John}{1} is a boy", "{Emily}{a} is a girl", ..., "{Alba}{f} is a brand"
);
```

I want to first sort the name in first `{}` by alphabet and then sort by second `{}` by hex number regardless of the word behind.

```
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;
my @sorted1 = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @sorted;
print "@sorted1\n";
```

I try something like this, but it does not work. How do I sort the array the way I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's obvious why your code didn't work.

```
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;
my @sorted1 = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @sorted;
```

Two problems here. Firstly, your second sort is just going to overwrite the first. The first sort you're running is completely pointless. Your code has exactly the same effect as:

```
my @sorted1 = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @array;
```

And secondly, you're sorting by the wrong things. Your first sort is sorting by the whole string and the second one sorts by the whole string passed through the `hex()` function (and given that your strings aren't valid hex strings, that's not a good idea).

Let's address the two issues separately.

What does it actually mean to sort by two different things? Usually, it implies a hierarchy in the sorts - one will be more important than the other. It means "sort by this and if two records have the same value as each other for that, then sort them by this secondary value". In your case, you're probably saying "sort by the string between the first pair of braces and if two records have the same value there, then sort by the hex value between the second pair of braces". The second sort value is a "tie-breaker" when the first sort value is the same in two records.

And Perl's `sort` is great for multi-level sorts like this. When you write a sort expression, it needs to return -1, 0 or 1. It returns -1 or 1 if the two values you're comparing are different and 0 if they are the same. And, as 0 is a false value to Perl, that makes it easy to stack sorts on top of each other.

```
my @sorted = sort {
   sort_expression_1
     or
   sort_expression_2
} @array;
```

If `sort_expression_1`  returns -1 or 1, then that's true and the Boolean expression "short-circuits" at that point. If the two values are the same, then `sort_expression_1` returns 0 and the Boolean expression goes on to evaluate `sort_expression_2`.

So what do we actually want to sort by? Well, we need to extract the strings between the braces and sort by those. Something like this, perhaps:

```
my @sorted = sort {
  # Extract the sortable bits into arrays
  my @a_bits = $a =~ /\{(.+?)}/g;
  my @b_bits = $b =~ /\{(.+?)}/g;

  # Compare the strings
  $a_bits[0] cmp $b_bits[0]
    or
  # If the strings are the same, compare the hex numbers
  hex($a_bits[1]) <=> hex($b_bits[i])
} @array;
```

For more efficient sorting, you can use the "[Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)" which breaks out the bits you want to sort by before starting the actual sort.

```
my @sorted =
  map { $_->[0] }
  sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or hex($a->[2]) <=> hex($b->[2]) }
  map { [ $_, /\{(.+?)}/g ] } @array;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the clear explanation. This help me more understand in `sort`.

Answer (score 4):

```
sort {
   my @a_keys = $a =~ /\{([^{}]*)\}/g;
   my @b_keys = $b =~ /\{([^{}]*)\}/g;

   $a_keys[0] cmp $b_keys[0]
      ||
   hex($a_keys[1]) <=> hex($b_keys[1])
}
```

Comment: Hi , i am not sure how to add the code above with my @array. Can you explain more to me?

Comment: `@sorted = sort { <ikegami answer> } @array`;

Comment: This type of sorting would greatly profit from a [Schwartzian Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).